# Variable declaration without an 'As' clause

Tags: vb.net

I have code that looks like this:

```
Private Shared Function Dec2Base(ByVal DecNum, ByVal Base) As String
    Dim NHD As Double
    Dim HN As String = ""

    While DecNum <> 0
        NHD = DecNum - (Int(DecNum / Base) * Base)
        HN = Mid("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", NHD + 1, 1) & HN
        DecNum = Int(DecNum / Base)
    End While

    Dec2Base = HN
End Function
```

It is causing this compile error:

```
Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed.
```

So I looked at the code and concluded that `DecNum` and `Base` where Integers and added the `As Integer` to the function declaration.

Then I stumbled on this call:

```
Public Shared Function SetP() As String
    Dim b = Format(Now(), "MMddyy")

    SetP = Dec2Base(b, 17)

End Function
```

And several like it.  That is: `DecNum` is being passed in as a String.

What is the proper way to eliminate the compile warning message?

1. `ByVal DecNum As String`?
2. `ByVal DecNum As Integer`?
3. Something else?

Exactly when is the type conversions happening in the existing code and how will that be changed by adding the `As` clause?

Comment: Older versions of VB would automatically convert between string and number types. It was very error-prone. I'd use `Integer`

Comment: I would have taken this opportunity to re-write the Function Dec2Base(). This will make my life easier for future maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the warning you can just use `ByVal DecNum as Object` but the behaviour may be undefined since it will implicitly convert it to a string or integer based on what was passed in. I would probably use the Integer type and re-write any calls to pass that in as the type.

Comment: Although this was the accepted answer in the end I need to do `As Decimal` because the number was too large to fit into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that DecNum and Base should most probably be Integers.

A few things I noticed:

Instead of using a string literal it would be better to use a Const variable.  This gives you the option of using string indexing instead of the `Mid` function.  The index will simply be the modulus of the number divided by the base.

One shortcut that vb.net has is a special Integer Division sign(`\`).  If you want the result of a division to be an integer you can use this sign and the casting is done automatically.

With these in mind your code could look something like this:

```
Private Function Dec2Base2(ByVal DecNum As Integer, ByVal Base As Integer) As String
    Const DIGITS As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim num = DecNum
    While num > 0
        s = DIGITS(num Mod Base) & s
        num = num \ Base
    End While
    Return s
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think StringBuilder is any faster when you have to Insert(0, x) for every change. In this case, it needs to do the same work you end up doing with regular concatenation. You can also get run of `Dim num = DecNum` and just use DecNum, since it's a value type and you're working with a copy.

Comment: String indexing works for normal strings too, but using `CONST` is still a good idea

Comment: I voted this answer up because of the effort put in and it is really a good answer, but I am giving the win to the simple answer from MWS because that is what I did.